# how to delete java keystore personal/private password

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

while testing an apache webservice/website (running on Windows 7) with an ssl certificate I must have created a java keystore where I set the same password that the certificate's private key has. I didn't pay much attention to the progress because I had to import and delete the same file over and over again. So now, whenever I open a file chooser on that site a java pop-up comes up (private keystore) asking me for the password, which is quite annoying.

I've tried reproducing this but I couldn't find a way to even set a password for a certificate. I know I didn't run any console commands.
Using keytool.exe -list just says the C:\users... .keystore couldn't be found.

I just want to get rid off this private keystore but I don't even know where to look for it or what it is named. I don't think it is the cacerts because it still has the standard password.

Removing java didn't help either. Could there be some tool installed on the system that created this file?

I hope you know a way to remove this keystore thing.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you've got this completely wrong. Java doesn't even run when the browser popups up file chooser dialogs, let alone ask for keystore passwords. I suggest the problem is located entirely within the browser, and therefore off topic,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

delete or rename the file **trusted.clientcerts** in the folder

> C:\Users\\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security

and the pop-up asking for the personal password is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to check about the browser keystores:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/keystores.html

I think all the browsers give the functionality of deleting imported certificates. Try to delete and re-import the cert to resolve your problem.

Comment: I think I found it. It happens within the java control panel under security -> certificates -> user -> Client authentication. There I get the question to put in a password for my personal keystore. I am on a different machine right now so I can't test it from here.